# Golang permutations of numbers, recursion not working

Tags: go, recursion, permutation

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func anon(n []int, sl []int, result [][]int) {
    if len(n) == 0 {
        result = append(result, sl)
        fmt.Printf("result %v\n", result)
        return
    }
    for i , _ := range n {
        fmt.Printf(" n %v\n", n)
        sl = append(sl, n[i])
        ab := append(n[:i], n[i+1:]...)
        fmt.Printf("i %v ---ab %v, sl %v, result %v ---\n",i, ab,sl,result )

        anon(ab, sl , result)
    }
}

func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    var sl1 = []int{}
    var result = [][]int{}
    anon(nums, sl1, result)
 return result
}

func main() {
  sl2 := []int{1,2}
  permute(sl2)
  
}
```

I am expecting 'result' as [[1,2], [2,1]]. However, when I look at the below output from the code run:

```
 n [1 2]
i 0 ---ab [2], sl [1], result [] ---
 n [2]
i 0 ---ab [], sl [1 2], result [] ---
result [[1 2]]
```

**n [2 2]**

**i 1 ---ab [2], sl [1 2], result [] ---**

```
 n [2]
i 0 ---ab [], sl [1 2 2], result [] ---
result [[1 2 2]]
```

I see for (in bold) i=1, I have ab[2], sl[1 2], result[] and n[2,2]. I am not able to get it working for Golang. Something similar works well with Python.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this complete sample, which can help you to understand better how to make a permutation with `golang`: https://go.dev/play/p/JKG_FtilQCz.

In Golang slices are pointers to arrays, and when you make `append(n[:i], n[i+1:]...)` you are adding a new value in variable `n`, so you are changing the initial `sl2` value, that should be {1,2} but is transformed in {2,2} as you noted. Try not to append in `n`, instead append in `ab` or something else.

Comment: Thanks @ronaldo  for quick answer.

Slices and recursion together was creating some confusion. After your comment, I took a closer and was able to solve it.